# Pie chart getting crashed

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am trying to achieve a pie chart using Charts swift library. I am getting an error in precoded file which comes with the charts library. Due to which my app is crashing. I have tried modifying the code there but showing the same error in the file. I also have attached the error screenshot after the sample code.

**UIViewController**

```
import UIKit
import Charts
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class pieView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pie1: PieChartView!
    let allCertificate = "URL HERE"
    let expiredCertificate = "URL HERE"
    let upcomingCertificate = "URL HERE"

    var tempAllArray  = [[String : AnyObject]]()
    var tempExpArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()
    var tempUpcomArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()

    var allCount = Double()
    var expiredCount = Double()
    var upcomingCount = Double()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getAllCertificate()
        getUpcomingCertificate()
        getExpiredCertificate()
    }

    func callingFunction(){
         print(allCount)

        let expPercent = (expiredCount / allCount) * 100
        let upcomPercent = (upcomingCount / allCount) * 100
        let otherPercent = ((allCount - (expiredCount + upcomingCount)) / allCount) * 100

        let months = ["Expired","Upcoming","Other"]
        let unitsSold = [expPercent, upcomPercent, otherPercent]

        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
        pie1.chartDescription?.text = ""
        pie1.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart"
    }

    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry1 = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: dataPoints[i] as AnyObject)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry1)
        }
       let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")


        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .percent
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.multiplier = 1.0

        let pieChartData = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
        pieChartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter:formatter))
        pie1.data = pieChartData
        pie1.centerText = "Certificate"
        pie1.usePercentValuesEnabled = true
        var colors: [UIColor] = [#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)]
        pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
        let legend = pie1.legend
        legend.setCustom(colors: colors, labels: ["Expired","Upcoming","Other"])
        legend.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14.0)!
    }


    func getAllCertificate() {
        Alamofire.request(self.allCertificate).responseJSON { response in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                    //                    print(resData)
                    self.allCount = Double(resData.count)
                    //                    print("all \(self.allCount)")
                }
            }
            else
            {
                self.allCount = 0
            }
            self.callingFunction()
        }
    }

    func getExpiredCertificate() {
        Alamofire.request(self.expiredCertificate).responseJSON { response in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                    //                    print(resData)
                    self.expiredCount = Double(resData.count)
                    //                    print("expired\(self.expiredCount)")
                }
            }
            else{
                self.expiredCount = 0
            }
            self.callingFunction()
        }
    }

    func getUpcomingCertificate() {
        Alamofire.request(self.upcomingCertificate).responseJSON { response in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                    //                    print(resData)
                    self.upcomingCount = Double(resData.count)
                    print("all \(self.upcomingCount)")

                }
            }
            self.callingFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Screenshot**

[image: chart error]

Comment: Please make sure your array should have value @Saurabh

Comment: what if it does not have value because my array values may vary. It could be zero also.

Comment: you can add the validation to your array , If it has value it should go inside otherwise dont

Comment: ok but how do I add validation in array?

Comment: Please post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable